# questions on nexus 3064

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus

In most of times i have worked with Juniper switches but in some cases i should use some Nexus 3064PX series(48x sfp+) so i have some questions :

1. as i remembered some switches such as 3750 has some issues with PBR , do we have still problem with PBR in nexus 3064?
2. i have around 4m PPS and around 10Gbps uplink with 6-7x GRE Tunnel and 7-8 BGP Session with no full table and around 1-2k routes, can nexus handle this without high cpu usages?
3. i already used some routers but with same amount of bps/pss i had some issues so i thought maybe switching to nexus 3064 help me to reduce load.

Thank you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

## PBR

PBR is supported ([guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/unicast/602_u1_1/l3_nx-os/l3_pbr.html#pgfId-1085859)) but keep in mind your related ACLs need to fit within the small TCAM allocation for PBR.

## GRE Tunnels

There are some caveats to GRE tunnels on Nexus 3000-series ([Cisco guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/interfaces/503_U4_1/b_Cisco_n3k_Interfaces_Configuration_Guide_503_u4_1/b_Cisco_n3k_Interfaces_Configuration_Guide_503_u4_1_chapter_0101.html) [another](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/interfaces/7_x/b_Cisco_Nexus_3000_Series_NX-OS_Interfaces_Configuration_Guide_7x/b_Cisco_Nexus_3000_Series_NX-OS_Interfaces_Configuration_Guide_7x_chapter_0100.html).)  There's a limit of 8 tunnels and there's no interface stats, ACLs, uRPF, or multicast support.  Also you need **Enterprise Services** feature license.

PBR and GRE tunnels are supposed to work together.  I haven't done this.

## Misc

You might refer to the guidance on [TCAM allocation](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/security/7x/b_Cisco_n3k_Security_Config_7x/b_Cisco_n3k_Security_Config_7x_chapter_0111.html), and understanding the [unicast RIB & FIB resource limits](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/unicast/503_u3_1/l3_nx-os/l3_manage-routes.html), while planning your project.

Going from Juniper to Nexus, you may want to familiarize yourself with the [commit/rollback system](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/system_mgmt/93x/system-management/b-cisco-nexus-3000-series-nx-os-system-management-configuration-guide-93x/b-cisco-nexus-3000-series-nx-os-system-management-configuration-guide-93x_chapter_011001.html) available on N3k.